# Get Points of Intersection with Sine Wave

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, calculus

I have a particle at a fixed position X and fixed amplitude AMP that travels on a sin wave.

I'd like to be able to dynamically change the period of the target sine wave WITHOUT moving the particle. (When I change the period, its X position doesn't line up to the same Y position of the graph with a different period, so it jumps all over the place.

I have a solution for this - Find where the graph with the new period intersects with the graph of the old period and create an X-offset, lining these two figures up.

For any given y on a sin wave, there will be 2 corresponding X values per period. I'm trying to get these two values. I'll then compare the derivatives to choose which one I want.

However, I don't know how to get both of these values. Any ideas?

Here's an image of what I'm after: [Sin Wave Logic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iuoeexr25omawe8/IMG_3843.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: I think this is more related to programmers or math sites than to stackoverflow.

Comment: Write down the equations. You have `y = A sin (w x + p)`. You wish to find a p for a given w such that x and y have particular values. You have an equation with four variables, three of which are known, so write down the equations, solve for the remaining variable you want. You'll need to use the arcsin function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a sine-wave defined by

```
y = sin(a*(x+c))+d
```

then you can reverse it by

```
x = (arcsin(y-d)-c)/a
```

for a given a.

This yields the solution in the range of [-pi;pi]

The other solution you are looking for is then `2*pi-x`

Comment: My sin wave is defined by: `y = a*sin(p*(x+c))+d` Therefore, would my final equation actually be: `x = arcsin( (y-d)/a )/p - c` Or should my sin wave actually be defined by: `y = a*sin((p*c)+x)+d?` Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @KeenanRebera You can define it the first way and your final equation is indeed `x = arcsin( (y-d)/a )/p - c`, as you wrote.

Comment: I ran a some test code on the algorithm and it seems really quite close. Importantly: If I change the x value the offset changes appropriately. However, the real effect I'm going for here is 'compressing a slinky' where one of the ends (Say the end on the y-axis) never moves, and the rest of it compresses backwards. This solution is really close but I can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: @KeenanRebera I can't quite follow that, perhaps it would be advisable to open a new question with a detailed description (and perhaps illustration) of the status quo and what you still want to enhance.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow a little cheating, you can use a cross-fading effect to get a smooth transition from f(t) to g(t) via

```
h(s,t)=(1-s)*f(t)+s*g(t)
```

while s as a function of t is between 0 and 1 and use something like

```
y = h( (t-ts)/d, t)
```

for the time period from `ts` to `ts+d`.